# getting category name from category id in ParkingArea table Laravel vue

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

hi guys in need of assistance , i am a bit confused , i have a categories table and i have a parkingarea table, i want to display the name of the category from the category id when listing the parking areas,

in my parkingArea model i have

```
    public function category(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
    }
```

also i am fetching from my parkingArea controller like

```
 public function parkingData()
    {
        return ParkingArea::with(['category'])->orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();
    }
```

and in my Area.vue file i have

```
loadParkingArea(){
                 axios.get("api/parkingArea").then(({ data }) => (this.parkingArea = data));  
                 console.log(this.data)
               
            },
```

and i am iterating as

```
 <tr v-for="Area in parkingArea.data" :key="Area.id">
                                <td> {{Area.category_id->name}} </td>
                                <td> {{Area.location}}</td>
                                <td>{{Area.capacity}}</td>
                            </tr>
```

PLEASE HELP OUT (developia)

Comment: You cannot mix php and vue. `Area.category_id.name`

Comment: @Maksim i just tried it, it doesnt work

Comment: @Maksim this `<td> {{Area.category_id.name}} </td>`  took out all. my table data with all other datas that where showing already

Answer (score 0):

Your axios response is storing it in the variable *data* so in your assignment

`this.parkingArea = data` should be `this.parkingArea = data.data`

or in your iteration

```
v-for="Area in parkingArea.data.data"
```

try it and comment

Comment: i tried it and this is what i got `app.js:48270 [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined"

found in

---> <Area> at resources/js/components/Admin/Area.vue
       <Root>`

Comment: Show me how the answer to your request reaches the front end

Answer (score 0):

hi guys its over 17 days , and figured this doesnt have an answer yet, so i solved it this way

1. establishing proper relationship- in my category.php i was using belongsto Instead of hasMany

```
public function parkingArea()
    {
        // return $this->belongsTo(ParkingArea::class);
        return $this->hasMany(\App\ParkingArea::class);
    }
```

also in ParkingArea.php

```
public function category(){
        return $this->belongsTo(\App\Category::class);
    }
```

once that was done.. all i had to do was in my vue file, i fetched my data thus

```
 loadParkingArea(){
                 axios.get("api/parkingArea").then(({ data }) => (this.parkingArea = data));  

               
            },
```

and i iterated like this to get the name of the category

```
  <tr v-for="Area in parkingArea.data" :key="Area.id">
    <td> {{Area.category.name}} </td>
    <td> {{Area.location}}</td>
    <td>{{Area.capacity}}</td>
  </tr>
```

thanks, and i hope this helps who ever needs it- Developia